# Language supported by LTL

Tags: model-checking

ltl p {(Xq) || (Fp)},

what will be the formal language accepted of this LTL formula?

For example :
 ltl p { p && (Xq)}

```
{w = a0a1a2.... | p∈a0 && q∈a1}
```

Answer (score 1):

The property `X q || F p` accepts words of the language

```
{ w = w0w1w2... | q ∈ w1 or ∃wi. p ∈ wi }
```

Another way to look at the accepted language is to draw the *Buchi Automaton* corresponding to the *LTL formula* `X q || F p`:

[image: buchi automaton]

> **Credits:** image generated with **[ltl2ba](http://www.lsv.ens-cachan.fr/~gastin/ltl2ba/index.php)**